# How to find a specific, pre-defined word surrounded by any word(s) starting with a capital letter(s)?

Tags: python, regex

I have been analyzing large amounts of text data. This is what I got so far:

```
(([A-Z][\w-]*)+\s+(\b(Study|Test)\b)(\s[A-Z][\w-]*)*)|(\b(Study|Test)\b)(\s[A-Z][\w-]*)+
```

Types of phrases I would like to capture:

- Europe National Longitudinal Study
- Longitudinal Study
- Study Initiative
- Longitudinal Study Initiative

I want to capture the word 'Study' or 'Test' ONLY if it is surrounded by the words starting with a capital letter. The ideal regex would achieve all of this + it would ignore\escape certain words like 'of' or 'the'.

- *the above regex is super slow with the str.findall function, I guess there must be a better solution
- ** I used https://regex101.com for testing and then run it in Jupyter, Python 3

Comment: Using `\s` can match a newline as well. Perhaps `[A-Z]\w+[^\S\r\n]+(Test|Study)\b|\b(Test|Study)[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w+` https://regex101.com/r/XjBaW5/1

Comment: The starting capital, `([A-Z][w-])+` seems to be missing a `\b`: `(\b[A-Z][w-])+`.  I don't know if marking non-capture parentheses as such, `(?:like so)` might improve speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 capture groups instead, and match a single word starting with a capital A-Z on the left or on the right.

Using `[^\S\r\n]` will match a whitespace char without a newline, as `\s` can match a newline

```
\b[A-Z]\w*[^\S\r\n]+(Test|Study)\b|\b(Test|Study)[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ys5wW3/1)

Comment: Or you could go completely crazy, postpone your housework, get trouble with the wife and create some way-out-of-scope define construct ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is possibly way out of the actual scope but you *could* use the newer `regex` module with subroutines:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<marker>\b[A-Z][-\w]*\b)
    (?<ws>[\ \t]+)
    (?<needle>\b(?:Study|Test))

    (?<pre>(?:(?&marker)(?&ws))+)
    (?<post>(?:(?&ws)(?&marker))+)

    (?<before>(?&pre)(?&needle))
    (?<after>(?&needle)(?&post))
    (?<both>(?&pre)(?&needle)(?&post))
)

(?&both)|(?&before)|(?&after)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PUHMlo/1/) (and mind the modifiers!).

---

In actual code, this could be:

```
import regex as re

junk = """


I have been analyzing large amounts of text data. This is what I got so far:

(([A-Z][\w-]*)+\s+(\b(Study|Test)\b)(\s[A-Z][\w-]*)*)|(\b(Study|Test)\b)(\s[A-Z][\w-]*)+

Types of phrases I would like to capture:

    Europe National Longitudinal Study
    Longitudinal Study
    Study Initiative
    Longitudinal Study Initiative

I want to capture the word 'Study' or 'Test' ONLY if it is surrounded by the words starting with a capital letter. The ideal regex would achieve all of this + it would ignore\escape certain words like 'of' or 'the'.

    *the above regex is super slow with the str.findall function, I guess there must be a better solution
    ** I used https://regex101.com for testing and then run it in Jupyter, Python 3


"""

pattern = re.compile(r'''
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<marker>\b[A-Z][-\w]*\b)
    (?<ws>[\ \t]+)
    (?<needle>\b(?:Study|Test))

    (?<pre>(?:(?&marker)(?&ws))+)
    (?<post>(?:(?&ws)(?&marker))+)

    (?<before>(?&pre)(?&needle))
    (?<after>(?&needle)(?&post))
    (?<both>(?&pre)(?&needle)(?&post))
)

(?&both)|(?&before)|(?&after)''', re.VERBOSE)

for match in pattern.finditer(junk):
    print(match.group(0))
```

And would yield

```
Europe National Longitudinal Study
Longitudinal Study
Study Initiative
Longitudinal Study Initiative
```

Comment: Brilliant :-)))

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:[A-Z]\w+\s+){0,5}\bStudy\b\s*(?:[A-Z]\w+\b\s*){0,5})
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/Ys5wW3/1)

I have to further test it to check whether it works for the all of the possible scenarios in a real world. I might need to adjust '5' in the expression to a lower or higher number(s) to optimize my algorithm's performance, though. I tested it on some real datasets already and the results have been promising so far. It is fast.